# Can't concatenate string with integer

Tags: python, string, list, int, concatenation

I was writing a script in Python to generate brute force wordlists. I already can concatenate only strings, but I cant concatenate some random numbers in the final of each word in list, because it says that I cannot concatenate str and int objects...

The code:

```
wList = []

words = raw_input("[+]Insert the words that you wish: ")
outputFile = raw_input("[+]Insert the path to save the file: ")

wordList = words.split(",")

for x in wordList:
    for y in wordList:
        wList.append(x + y)
        wList.append(y + x)
        wList.append(x + "-" + y)
        wList.append(y + "-" + x)
        wList.append(x + "_" + y)
        wList.append(y + "_" + x)
        wList.append(x + "@" + y)
        wList.append(y + "@" + x)


for num in wordList:
    for num2 in wordList:
        for salt in range(1,10):
            wList.append(num + num2 + int(salt))
            wList.append(num2 + num + int(salt))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only concatenate a `string` with another `string` in Python.

Change the last two lines to below:

```
wList.append(num + num2 + str(salt))
wList.append(num2 + num + str(salt))
```

Comment: It works ! It was absolutely simple to solve, but i'm nem to Python.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In python the `+` operator after a `sequence` calls `concat` with the `sequence` before the operator and whatever is after the operator. In python `string` is a `sequence`. The `concat` function only works on two sequences of the same type, i.e. two strings or two arrays. In your code you use this operator for `string` and `int`.

You need to change all of the places you concatenate strings with ints. Here are two possible ways to do this.

You could make all the ints into strings. For example:

```
wList.append(str(x) + "-" + str(y))
```

Or you could use %-formatting. For example:

```
wList.append("%d-%d"%(x, y))
```